# How to know that all threads completed in spring boot @async with @scheduled

Tags: spring, asynchronous, completable-future

I need to call REST API (50 calls at a time )using async. Each call takes some time(20 seconds) to response and after that some processing happens. Then need to know when all threads are completed, once all threads are done again need to call that api with 50 Threads. How it can be achieved in spring.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like [Project reactor](https://projectreactor.io). It gives you a flexible way to construct the things that you're asking about.

Here is an example of the possible implementation:

```
@Async
@Scheduled(cron = "*/10 * * * * *")
public void job() {
    log.info("Cron job has been triggered");
    Flux<ResponseEntity<Void>> externalCall = Flux
            .range(1, 5)
            .parallel()
            .runOn(elastic())
            .flatMap(i -> {
                log.info("Call external service {}", i);
                return webClient.get().retrieve().toBodilessEntity();
            })
            .sequential();

    Flux
            .from(externalCall)
            .thenMany(Flux.defer(
                    () -> {
                        log.info("First execution completed. Call external service one more time");
                        return externalCall;
                    })
            )
            .last()
            .subscribe(i -> log.info("Execution completed"));
}
```

I also prepared a minimal project that you can find in [my repository](https://github.com/TsybulskyStepan/stackoverflow).

You can run the project using the following command : `./mvnw -pl async-scheduled-call-external-service clean spring-boot:run`

Comment: I will go through ur solution Stepan, I was wondering whether spring itself has some handler to know whether all threads are completed.

Comment: Personally, I can't recall such in Spring. You can also use Java built-in **CompletableFuture** but Project reactor provides more elegant way. I hope you will like it.